# Windows Firewall netsh equivalent of iptables u32 module

Tags: windows, firewalls

I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a netsh equivalent of the u32 module for iptables. I want to create a rule to Drop a packet that starts with a specific set of bytes.
Similar to:

```
# Block rules
iptables -t filter -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 443  -m u32 --u32 \
"52=0x18030000:0x1803FFFF" -j DROP
```

Is this possible with netsh ?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you have to write your own callout driver to accomplish this. You can't inspect packets in user mode [Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See [Windows Filtering Platform Callout Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff571068.aspx) on MSDN.